# Get some translations symfony2

Tags: symfony

I get translations so:

```
$translated = $this->container->get('translator')
        ->getCatalogue($language)
        ->all();
```

But so I have all the translations.

For example, there is a file with the following content:

```
symfony:
    is:
        great: Symfony is great
        amazing: Symfony is amazing
    has:
        bundles: Symfony has bundles
user:
    login: Login
```

How can I get only certain ones (only user or only symfony)? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:**
Did so:

```
$messages = [];
foreach ($translated['messages'] as $key => $message) {
    if (stripos($key, 'frontend')) {
        $messages[$key] = $message;
    }
}
```

But is there no such functional built in?

Comment: From which criteria do you want certain translations ?

Answer (score 1):

[From the doc:](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#basic-translation)

```
$translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Symfony is great');
```

EDIT:

Looking at your updated question, if you have a look at MessageCatalogueInterface, I think you could do something like catalogue->all('yourdomain'), if you would organise your tranlations into domains.

Have a look here:

> ```
> /**
>  * Gets the messages within a given domain.
>  *
>  * If $domain is null, it returns all messages.
>  *
>  * @param string $domain The domain name
>  *
>  * @return array An array of messages
>  */
> public function all($domain = null);
> ```

Comment: Not what I need

Comment: Not after you updated your question no. As they have replied to you now, what you want to do it is not possible to do that as the translations are not really 'nested'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added my decision to the question, is not there something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive certain translations, transfer them to another file with the proper domain name (in my example this will be the frontend):

[image]

And now I can get translations as follows:

```
$messages = $this->container->get('translator')
    ->getCatalogue($language)
    ->all('frontend');
```

Thanks for the tip [strnm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2507740/strnm)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Consider accepting my answer as valid if that worked out for your problem : )

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible as while reading the translation file Symfony normalises the keys that are nested in your YAML file. Thus, the catalog will only contain the message keys `symfony.is.great`, `symfony.is.amazing`, `symfony.has.bundles`, and `user.login`.

Being able to nest keys is only syntactic sugar provided by the Translation component's `YamlFileLoader` class.

Comment: It turns out that I can get only all the translations and can not only part?

Comment: Yes, as there is nothing like a part of the translation in the generated message catalog.